# Преобразование элемента массива в Number

Tags: javascript, массивы, преобразование

Возникла проблема при написании калькулятора

```
for (var i = 0; i < calcBtn.length; i++){
    calcBtn[i] = calcBtn.innerHTML;
    calcBtn[i].onclick = function btnClick() {
        +this;
        console.log(typeof this);  
        calcInput.value += this.innerHTML;

    }
}
```

Необходимо преобразовать объект, полученный из массива при клике, в переменную типа Number, чтобы в дальнейшем выполнить математическую операцию.

typeof this выводит object, а +this никак не преобразовывает, не могу понять почему?
Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает?

Comment: Что насчёт `+this.innerHTML`?

Comment: `calcBtn[i] = calcBtn.innerHTML;` - это что делает? Уберите эту строчку.

Comment: для простого калькулятора  нужен метод eval(); с ним тебе будет проще чтобы не заморачиватся

Comment: _+this никак не преобразовывает_ - преобразовывает, просто ты никуда результат не сохраняешь.

Comment: покажи что у тебя находится в массиве calcBtn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var calcInput = document.getElementById("calcinput");
var calcBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".calc-btn");
for (var i = 0; i < calcBtn.length; i++){
    calcBtn[i].onclick = function() {
        var buttonValue = +this.innerText;
        console.log(typeof buttonValue);
        console.log(buttonValue);
        calcInput.value += this.innerHTML;
    };
}
```

```css
.calc-btn
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-btn">1</div>
<div class="calc-btn">2</div>
<div class="calc-btn">3</div>
<div class="calc-btn">4</div>
<div class="calc-btn">+</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<input id="calcinput"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все понял